# inner join aliases not working

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am tryng to compare race codes in two different tables joining on a number id in each table, one table is in fixed positional format. I am getting an error on the '.' between T2.DSNumber on line 5

```
select 
    T1.SNumber, 
    T1.Racecode1, 
    T1.Race1 , 
    SUBSTRING(rec,1,6) as T2.DSNumber,
    SUBSTRING(rec,175,2) as T2.DSRaceCode1,
    SUBSTRING(rec,251,12) as T2.DSRaceText1
 from scerts  T1
 INNER JOIN DS2012 T2
 on T1.SNumber = T2.DSNumber
 where right(T1.SNumber,6) = T2.DSNumber and T1.Racecode1 <>T2.DSRaceCode1
    and  T1.FLAG = 'o'
    and year(cast(T1.DDate as date)) ='2012' 
    order by T1.SNumber
```

Comment: Remove the `T2.` from the name of the columns...

Comment: I tried, but now it does not recognize the DS columns.  I tried  putting DS fields in temp table before doing join but had similar problem with alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you are using SQL Server. In your query the below part is wrong

```
SUBSTRING(rec,1,6) as T2.DSNumber,
```

should be

```
SUBSTRING(rec,1,6) as DSNumber,
SUBSTRING(rec,175,2) as DSRaceCode1,
SUBSTRING(rec,251,12) as DSRaceText1
```

Answer (score 2):

Others apparently are close with different answers, but your issue is that your second table (T2) does not actually have columns for "DSNumber" and "DSRaceCode1" as you are pulling those from the substring components.  Therefore, those substring references need to be applied to your join (or WHERE).  I have formatted to JOIN condition SQL format.  You can't give an alias.column as a column name as you attempted to do, but enough info to provide what SHOULD be proper syntax for you to move forward.

Also, for future, and hopefully can apply to what you have via table structure changes, use id-based columns for joins and not getting into "merged" fields into a single will kill your performance, querying and support down-stream.

```
select 
      T1.SNumber, 
      T1.Racecode1, 
      T1.Race1, 
      SUBSTRING(T2.rec,1,6) as DSNumber,
      SUBSTRING(T2.rec,175,2) as DSRaceCode1,
      SUBSTRING(T2.rec,251,12) as DSRaceText1
   from 
      scerts  T1
         INNER JOIN DS2012 T2
            on right(T1.SNumber,6) = SUBSTRING(T2.rec,1,6)
            AND T1.Racecode1 <> SUBSTRING(T2.rec,175,2)
 where 
        T1.FLAG = 'o'
    and year(cast(T1.DDate as date))
```

Also.. seeing sample data from each respective table would definitely have helped the many others that tried to answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should just remove the `T2.` from the alias you are giving the column.  If you decide you need it, then you need to escape it with quotation marks or brackets:

```
select field as [test.test]
select field as 'test.test'
```

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34220

Answer (score 0):

After

> as

you should define Alias Name for Fields not field itselft
Your query might be some thing like this

I think your table are structure as

```
T1 = SNNumber, RACECODE1 and RACE1
T2 = REC
```

if this this true  then you could used

```
SELECT  
            SUBSTRING(T2.rec,1,6) as DSNumber, 
            SUBSTRING(T2.rec,175,2) as DSRaceCode1, 
            SUBSTRING(T2.rec,251,12) as DSRaceText1
FROM        scerts T1
INNER JOIN  DS2012 T2 ON T1.SNNumber = RIGHT(T2.rec,6)
WHERE       T1.racecode1 <>  SUBSTRING(T2.rec,175,2)
AND         T1.FLAG = 'o' 
AND         year(cast(T1.DDate as date)) ='2012' 
ORDER BY    T1.SNumber
```

Hope this work

Comment: Select 
SUBSTRING(rec,1,6) as DSNumber,
SUBSTRING(rec,175,2) as DSRaceCode1,
SUBSTRING(rec,251,12) as DSRaceText1
into #tDSdata
from DS2012
select 
T1.SNumber, 
T1.RACECODE1, 
T1.RACE1 , 
T2.DSNumber,
T2.DSRaceCode1,
T2.DSRaceText1
from scerts  T1
INNER JOIN #tDSdata T2
on right(T1.SNumber,6) = T2.DSNumber
WHERE t1.racecode1 <> T2.DSRaceCode1
and  T1.FLAG = 'o'
 and year(cast(T1.DDate as date)) ='2012' 
 order by T1.SNumber

Comment: I created the temp table for the fixed position data then did the join. I guess I cant pull data from fixed position and insert in columns in same select as Join.

Answer (score -1):

I created the temp table for the fixed position data then did the join.  This time it worked.  I guess I cant pull data from fixed position and insert in columns in same select as Join statement.

```
Select  
  SUBSTRING(rec,1,6) as DSNumber,
  SUBSTRING(rec,175,2) as DSRaceCode1,
  SUBSTRING(rec,251,12) as DSRaceText1
into #tDSdata
from DS2012

select 
   T1.SNumber, 
   T1.RACECODE1, 
   T1.RACE1 , 
   T2.DSNumber,
   T2.DSRaceCode1,
   T2.DSRaceText1
from scerts  T1
INNER JOIN #tDSdata T2
on right(T1.SNumber,6) = T2.DSNumber
WHERE t1.racecode1 <> T2.DSRaceCode1
   and  T1.FLAG = 'o'
   and year(cast(T1.DDate as date)) ='2012' 
order by T1.SNumber
```